# __modver_version_show undefined error during make

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

Platform: Ubuntu 11.10 64bit
Kernel to be compiled:  3.2.1

Error after make:
`ERROR: "__modver_version_show" [drivers/staging/rts5139/rts5139.ko] undefined!`

To solve this I copied the .config file of a previous build kernel on the same machine to the same one.
Ran make menuconfig.
Saved it without any changes.
Ran make.

Make said that the bzImage is ready, but also gave the above error.

Comment: is your problem like [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/360089/modver-version-show-undefined-error-when-building-linux-kernel-3-0-4-version) ?

Comment: @Coren yes, and I have already tried that, didn't work, moreover that is the wrong forum for this question.

Comment: The kernel itself was compiled successfully, but not the modules. If the previous build was of a different kernel version, did you try `make oldconfig`?

Comment: related:
http://superuser.com/questions/360089/modver-version-show-undefined-error-when-building-linux-kernel-3-0-4-version

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the compiler or linker is dropping that function from the
build since it cannot see any references to it... Did you tried this patch: https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/1/19/492? It didn't solve it for me.

Comment: Well, no I didn't try that. I have now compiled the Ubuntu's kernel 3.2.1 successfully, and removed the Kernel.org's 3.2.1.